# How to solve AADSTS700016 error on login with Microsoft account?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I was following this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to enable login or registration via an MS account on my website. I did everything instructed on the page and getting this error while trying to use the feature.

> Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
>
> AADSTS700016: Application with an identifier
> '1xx3exx6-e70a-4xxa-bxx9-dd3fxx09xx93' was not found in the directory
> '5xx3dxxf-31cb-4xx4-9xx7-10bcxx12xxf0'. This can happen if the
> application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant
> or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your
> authentication request to the wrong tenant.

I tried creating a new solution and registered for a new key and got the same errors. What possibly went wrong and how can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can be below reasons that are causing this error:

- Make sure you are using `Application ID` as `Client ID`.
- This error means you have made a mistakes while configuring the `Client ID` OR `tenant ID` in your code, first confirm that both are appropriate as per your Service Principle (it's `tenant ID` and `Client ID`).

Comment: Where should the ApplicationID be used as Client ID?

Comment: If I am using my mail id as client id and password as a client secret, then will it work? my code's body is $body = @{
    "resource" = "https://management.azure.com/";
    "grant_type" = "client_credentials";
    "client_id" = "aj123@mycustomer.com"
    "client_secret" = "MyPassword!"
}

Comment: @singhh-msft please reply to my above comment.

Comment: Hi, no, Client ID will be a GUID.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, found that I used an app ID on the authentication provider that I removed, but did not subsequently update the identity provider.

App Service > (my app) > Settings > Authentication > Identity Provider > +Add provider

[image]

After removing the old api app id and adding the correct one it worked as expected.